# Command to save all settings to get it back later

Tags: renewcommand

Is there a command which save all current settings in my document (like margin size for example) so that I can use it after I apply some changes? For example I would like to change some things in a particular section and then go back to the old settings for other sections. What is the best practice in that case?

Comment: Depending on what you mean exactly by "settings", maybe you could use the commands `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` from the package `geometry`.

Comment: I want to anser "Use groups.", but depending on your application, that won't work (if you need to apply and undo global changes). If that's the case, you will have to be more specific. If not: Just use groups.

Comment: groups looks promising, thanks :)

Comment: There are many things that can be localized in groups and have changes made locally. But margins are not one of them. Dynamically changing margins, especially not at page boundaries, is tricky to say the least in LaTeX. It may be better for you to edit your question to be much more precise about what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: @schtandard I tried to use group to change `\arrayrulecolor` only for tables inside my group but the color has changes also for tables outside my group. Why?